# Unique sums for each pairing of numbers from 1 to 6

Tags: combinatorics

Q: Suppose we have the values $1$ to $6$ in a bowl. We draw them without replacement, noting the order in which we selected them. We multiply the first two values together, the next two values together, and the last two values together. Lastly, we add the three products above. How many unique sums are possible?

Approach: By using basic combinatorics, the total number of unique pairings would come out to be 15. But the solution also mentions that each of these sums would be unique. I wrote $\{1,..., 6\}$ as $\{i, i+1,..., i+5\}$. If you multiply any pairing in this, the coefficients of $i^2$ and $i$ would be the same; the constant term differs with each pairing, though. This just changed the problem from pairings of $\{1,...,6\}$ to $\{0,...,5\}$. Ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: By quick try-out, only 28, 29, 31, 32, 35, 37, 49, 41, 44 are possible.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think 15 unique sums do exist. But yeah is there a mathematical way apart from try outs, if we wanna do for n lets say